# Less & analog for relative selector

Tags: css, less

Here's what the output needs to be:

```
.root {...}
.node {...}
.root .red .node {border-color: red;}
.root .green .node {border-color: green;}
.root .blue .node {border-color: blue;}
```

I expected that it can be done in this way:

```
.root {
    // styles for .root
    ...
    .node {
        // styles for .node
        ...  
        .red & {border-color: red;} 
        .green & {border-color: green;} 
        .blue & {border-color: blue;} 
    }
}
```

but & matches '.root .node' selector.

It will be great to write styles for .node in one block of code.
Is there any analog of & but for local selectors?
May be there is some 'switch' that allows to generate styles accordingly to parent class.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the & works as in SASS it will insert the entire selector chain to that point, so it's behaving as expected. You need something like the following:

```
.node {
    // styles for .node
    ...  
}
.root {
    // styles for .root
    ...
    .red .node {border-color: red;} 
    .green .node {border-color: green;} 
    .blue .node {border-color: blue;} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `.node` code together, then you will need to do some repetition of `.root`, like so:

```
.root {/*root only*/}
.node {
  /*node only*/
  .root .red & {border-color: red;}
  .root .green & {border-color: green;}
  .root .blue & {border-color: blue;}
}
```

But then the question is, do you really need that specificity. In other words, the following may work just as well *without* repetition of `.root` if a `.node` always exists inside a `.root` in the html, or at least if `.root` does not affect the coloring of `.node` whether or not `.node` exists inside `.root`. Sometimes in a developer's desire to "nest" with LESS, it can be forgotten that the added specificity of the selector gained by the nesting may be superfluous.

```
.root {/*root only*/}
.node {
  /*node only*/
  .red & {border-color: red;}
  .green & {border-color: green;}
  .blue & {border-color: blue;}
}
```